# positioning of message success in JSON using REST

Tags: java, json, rest

i am implementing a GET using REST API in java so i am almost done with everything and i just want to generate the json to display now but the problem i am getting while putting the values in JSONObject is that **i want the `("message":"success")` to be shown at the last** that is after i have displayed both the other objects. but i cant figure out how i have tried moving it to different places but still i get `("message":"success")` in the middle of the both objects

```
JSONObject reply = new JSONObject();
reply.put("message", "SUCCESS");
reply.put("Leaderboard", activitySeqArray);
reply.put("Currentposition", act);
```

JSON looks like this

```
{
    "Leaderboard": [
        {
            "HighScore": "3333",
            "ProxyName": "user1"
        },
        {
            "HighScore": "2222",
            "ProxyName": "user2"
        },
        {
            "HighScore": "1111",
            "ProxyName": "user3"
        },
        {
            "HighScore": "1111",
            "ProxyName": "user4"
        }
    ],
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "Currentposition": {
        "PatientPosition": "3",
        "PatientProxyName": "user",
        "PatientHighScore": "1111"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON key-value object is an unordered set, please see the specification at [json](https://www.json.org/). If you want to keep order, you need to use an array. So the JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Leaderboard": []
    },
    {
        "Currentposition": {}
    },
    {
        "message": "SUCCESS"
    }
]
```